# Xcode 7.3 Old autocomplete

Tags: xcode, autocomplete, xcode7

The new Xcode 7.3 autocomplete is so slow and quite frustrating. Is there any possible way to go back to the old autocomplete without changing xcode versions? It is very slow and has a hard time finding classnames and really anything else...

Comment: I would like to go back to the Starts with!  Does anyone know how to do this?  How can a contains match outrank a starts with match?

Answer (score 0):

As of right now there are no ways to modify the autocomplete in Xcode. As versions progress, Apple overwrites code and has not set aside a specific version of Autocomplete - they simply update Autocomplete with the version.